# Are there alternatives to JMagick and ImageBuffer/ImageIO for Java for resizing/cropping images?

Tags: java, image-processing, maven, resize, crop

I'm currently using ImageBuffer/ImageIO. It works just fine on Windows, but for some reason, it is failing for PNG files on Linux. I have no idea why.

I think I just need to use another library. Because I develop on Windows, I'd like something that works on both systems effortlessly, and doesn't need to call into a process if I can avoid it. I don't want to deal with configuration hell, or require that some binary exist locally on the system somewhere just for the tests to pass.

Is there something out there that can help, or is ImageMagick pretty much the only option? It doesn't seem like Java has any nice options for working with images :(

I would also like something that just plugs into Maven and works, just like any other library. My past experiences with java image libraries has taught me that it's not really up to speed with Maven and are kind of ancient (I can't remember which library this way... but I just don't want to deal with configuration and deployment problems honestly... I just want to call into a nice API).

Thanks

Comment: Do png files work on Windows? Java Tutorial says, that PNG is always supported.

Comment: And maybe you can show us the error which you see?

Comment: Yes, the png files worked on windows. The problem was that an ImageBuffer containing a PNG on linux (debian-lenny) was returning 0 when getType() was called when it should have been returning 5. So I just put in a hack that tests for 0 and put in 5 manually. I know this sucks and is hacky, but it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to using [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) because it had some more flexible filtering and anti-aliasing I needed when resizing PNGs in a Java program. I haven't had any issues running on Windows or Linux - both seem to work fine.

Comment: I'm using it with maven.... I may have had to manually import the .jar into my Maven repository, I can't remember. I haven't had any troubles with it, though.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You'd think they'd just add it to a maven repository after 4 years since their last update :/ It's just a pain to create and checkin a script that installs the jars in the .m2 director for each person/computer working on the project and making sure it's consistent and working for everyone. Problem could be so easily solved if they just added it to maven repository :/

Comment: Just add it once to your enterprise's repo, and let Maven download it to your local one.

Comment: Yeah I guess, it's just annoying making an enterprise repo for 1 library. I like complaining. Sun/oracle make a bunch of apis/libraries, and 99% of them are accessible through maven... but then you got this JAI outlier that hasn't been updated in 4 years and there are no good alternatives... and it forces people to put in a ton of effort just to get access to it. It just time consuming to even get the thing going. The rails people already have everything finished by that time. It's just annoying how long everything takes in the Java world to do such simple things.